# Odd behaviour with PHP str_replace using $amp on arrays of data

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have 2 URLS in which I'd like to replace '&' with '&amp' and '#' with '%23', so I though I'd use:

```
list($upUrl, $downUrl) = str_replace(["&", "#"], ["&amp", "%23"], [$upUrl, $downUrl]);
```

but the replace for '&amp' doesn't happen - the '&' is left untouched. Using str_replace without arays works OK:

```
$upUrl = str_replace("&", "&amp", $upUrl);
```

If I change the '&amp' to another string, it works OK. Here's a code snippet to demonstrate the issue:

```
<?php
define("NL", "\n<br>");

$upUrl = "upUrl ampersand=& hash=#";
$downUrl = "downUrl ampersand=& hash=#";

echo $upUrl.NL;
echo $downUrl.NL.NL;

list($upUrl, $downUrl) = str_replace(["&", "#"], ["&amp", "%23"], [$upUrl, $downUrl]);

echo $upUrl.NL;
echo $downUrl.NL.NL;

$upUrl = str_replace("&", "&amp", $upUrl);

echo $upUrl.NL;
echo $downUrl.NL;

?>
```

Escaping the '&' with '\' makes no difference.

**Question: Am I doing something wrong or is this just a quirk of PHP?**

Comment: Are you running this script from CLI or webserver? (And it should be `&amp;`, not `&amp`) (Script seems to be running fine, run it from CLI to see the replacements being made)

Comment: This code snippet I'm running in a Tryit editor at W3schools. In real life, I'll be running it in a CGI script on my web server (thanks for the ';' - just missed it). Currently I'm running 4 `str_replace` statements to replace both '&' and '#' in each of my 2 urls, which works but looks messy.

Comment: That's probably because browsers will show `&amp;` as `&` and it _looks like_ no replacements have been made.

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me on the command line.

Comment: Ditch w3schools: https://3v4l.org/6sPSR

Comment: @kerbholz Brilliant - thanks. Completely missed that :-) Make it an answer and I'll upvote it. Only been doing PHP for about 3 weeks so find W3Schools useful for reference but I'll use that editor from now on.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Comment: I wonder what case you have where the ampersand needs to be HTML-encoded, while the hash is urlencoded. Shouldn't you just use `htmlspecialchars()` or `urlencode()`, depending on what you are doing with these values?

Comment: @FerdyPruis I'm not sure. Being new to PHP I discover better ways to do things very rapidly. This example is for URLs to be encoded in an SVG file..

Comment: @SteveIves In an url, an ampersand should be encoded as '%26'. 
'&amp;' is an HTML entity. You might also have to encode the '='. but it's unclear from your question what it is exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this code in the browser makes it *look like* no replacements were made, but they actually are, it's just that `&amp;` (and even your "faulty" `&amp`) are shown as `&` in a browser. Your code works as intended:

```
upUrl ampersand=& hash=#
<br>downUrl ampersand=& hash=#
<br>
<br>upUrl ampersand=&amp hash=%23
<br>downUrl ampersand=&amp hash=%23
<br>
<br>upUrl ampersand=&ampamp hash=%23
<br>downUrl ampersand=&amp hash=%23
<br>
```

https://3v4l.org/6sPSR